# How do I assign a value to the Source field of a Case record in Apex?

Tags: apex

I am trying to dynamically create a Case record in Apex and assign a value to its Source field, but I am getting the following error:

```
Field is not writeable: Case.Source
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
// Create out-of-office Email Message
Boolean IS_EMAIL_INCOMING = true;
String SUBJECT_OUT_OF_OFFICE = 'Automatic reply: Technical Support - Case #0012345 - Disable Module';
String TEXT_BODY_OUT_OF_OFFICE = 'I will be out of the office 10/11 thru 10/15.';
EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(
    Subject = SUBJECT_OUT_OF_OFFICE,
    TextBody = TEXT_BODY_OUT_OF_OFFICE,
    Incoming = IS_EMAIL_INCOMING
);

insert email;

// Create Case
String ORIGIN_CORPORATE = 'Email Unauthenticated - support@email.com';
String STATUS_NEW = 'New';
Boolean PREVENT_AUTO_RESPONSE = false;
Case caseWithEmail = new Case(
    Origin = ORIGIN_CORPORATE,
    Status = STATUS_NEW,
    Don_t_Send_Auto_Response__c = PREVENT_AUTO_RESPONSE,
    Source = email // The error is raised here. I have also tried email.Id.
);

insert caseWithEmail;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Source` is an `EmailMessage` object; you would use it to get the email message details in a query. Instead, you need to use the `SourceId` field to set the ID value:

```
SourceId = email.Id
```